# in search of a transformation between determinants

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, lattices

Motivated by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258284/is-the-matrix-left2m-choose-2j-i-right-i-j-12m-1-nonsingular/258291#258291). Consider the two matrices $A_n$ and $B_n$ with entries $\binom{2j}i$ and $\binom{n+1}{2j-i}$, respectively; for $1\leq i, \,j\leq n$.

I can show $\det A_n=\det B_n=2^{\binom{n+1}2}$; it is not a problem (see, for instance, [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258284/is-the-matrix-left2m-choose-2j-i-right-i-j-12m-1-nonsingular/258291#258291)).

> **Question.**
>
> (1) Is there a transformation converting $A_n$ into $B_n$ (or vice-versa)?
>
> (2) Is there a combinatorial interpretation/bijection revealing the counts by $\det A_n$ and $\det B_n$?

My asking for (2) is due to the fact that $2^{\binom{n+1}2}$ enumerates domino tilings of an [Aztec diamond](https://www.mfo.de/math-in-public/snapshots/files/domino-tilings-of-the-aztec-diamond).

> (3) Let $s(k)=$the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $k$. Then, $A_n$ and $B_n$ share the same [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) (showing the diagonal vector) given by
> $$[2^{\max(4k-2n+s(n-k)-s(k),0)}:\, 1\leq k\leq n].$$
> This claim is based on data from Noam Elkies' comments seen below. Any proof?

**Remark.** Let $\lceil x\rceil=$the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$ (*ceiling function*). So, (3) implies
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\max(4k-2n+s(n-k)-s(k),0)=\frac{n(n+1)}2;$$
Or, equivalently $\sum_{k=\lceil\frac{n}2\rceil}^n(s(k)-s(n-k))=\lceil\frac{n}2\rceil$.

Comment: FWIW $A$ and $B$ have the same Smith normal form for $n\leq 40$.  Here are the exponents of $2$ in the SNF for $n\leq 16$; the formula might be complicated . . .  $$[1],[3],[4,2],[7,3],[8,6,1],[10,7,4],[11,9,5,3],[15,10,7,4],[16,14,8,6,1],[18,15,12,7,3],[19,17,13,11,4,2],[22,18,15,12,8,3],[23,21,16,14,9,7,1],[25,22,19,15,11,8,5],[26,24,20,18,12,10,6,4],[31,25,22,19,15,11,8,5]$$

Comment: Aztec diamonds, lattice paths, and Schur functions are closely related. Might be something there.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: the leading numbers $1,3,4,7,8,10,11,15,16,18,19,22,\dots$ are the $2$-adic valuations $\nu((2n)!)$

Comment: And the differences $2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6$ between the first and second exponents for $n=3,4,5,\ldots,16$ are $\nu(4n)$.

Comment: **gp** code: **A(n) = matrix(n,n,i,j,binomial(2*j,i))**
$\phantom{000000000000000000000}$
**B(n)=matrix(n,n,i,j,binomial(n+1,2*j-i))**
$\phantom{000000000000000000000}$
**S(M)=round(log(matsnf(M,4))/log(2))**
$$ $$ and then the vector in my first comment is both 
**vector(16,n,S(A(n)))** and **vector(16,n,S(B(n)))**

Comment: I use Maple software. What are you using?

Comment: **gp**, as per the start of my comment.  http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/doc.html

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: I've made a conjecture on these Smith normal forms, see above.

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan I noticed the same thing last night.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is such a transformation, of the form predicted in [Linear transformation that preserves the determinant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/522/linear-transformation-that-preserves-the-determinant?rq=1).

Denoting $R$  the involution matrix $e_i\mapsto e_{n+1-i}$, it turns out that the matrix $A$ has an $LU$-decomposition in which $U:=\left[{j\choose i}\right]_{{1\le i\le n}\atop{1\le j\le n}}$, and the lower triangular part  is  $L=RCR$, where $C$ is the upper triangular matrix in [Suvrit's decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258284/is-the-matrix-left2m-choose-2j-i-right-i-j-12m-1-nonsingular/258609#258609) , 
$B=VCV^{-1}$ (*warning*:  $B$ of this question is named "$A$" there). So $B= (VR) A(VRU)^{-1}$, with $\det(VR)=\det(VRU)^{-1}=1$.

$$*$$
*[edit]* The description becomes a bit more gracious if we include the indices $i=0$ and $j=0$. So, if we define the $n\times n$ matrices with integer entries
$$A_n:=\left[{2j\choose i}\right]_{{0\le i< n}\atop{0\le j< n}}\qquad B_n:=\left[{n\choose 2j-i}\right]_{{0\le i< n}\atop{0\le j< n}}$$
$$U_n:=\left[{j\choose i}\right]_{{0\le i< n}\atop{0\le j< n}}\qquad L_n:=\left[2^{2j-i}{j\choose2j- i}\right]_{{0\le i< n}\atop{0\le j< n}}$$
$$N_n:=\Big[ \delta_{i+1,j}\Big]_{{0\le i< n}\atop{0\le j< n}}\qquad R_n:=\Big[ \delta_{n-i,j}\Big]_{{0\le i< n}\atop{0\le j< n}}$$
Then, (hiding the subscript $n$) 
$$A=LU$$
and
$$B=VCV^{-1}$$
with
$$V:=U^{T}R\qquad C:=(I+N)AU^{-1}\ .$$

Comment: Nice! I almost had a similar LU decomposition but did not get exactly what I wanted. It is also interesting to note that there exist numerous diagonal matrices for which $D^{-1}AD$ has an LU decomposition with the eigenvalues of $B$ on its diagonal, which reveals the same determinant but does not yet transform one matrix into another...

Comment: I enjoyed this.

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't answer the original question but answers the later SNF
question for the matrix $B_n$.  Let $C_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix
whose $(i,j)$-entry ($1\leq i,j\leq n$) is $\binom{x+1}{2j-i}$. Up to
row and column permutations that preserve the sign of the determinant,
this is the dual Jacobi-Trudi matrix for
the Schur function $s_{n,n-1,\dots,1}$, specialized by setting $x+1$
variables equal to 1 and the others to 0. I compute the SNF of this
matrix over the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ in
http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/jtsnf.pdf. Now set $x=n$ and
consider the SNF over $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$ (the integers localized at 2,
i.e., invert all primes except 2). My proof technique
can still be used since all hook lengths are odd and therefore units
in $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}$. Namely, one shows that the bottom-left $k\times
k$ minor $M$ divides all $k\times k$ minors (with a special argument
when $M=0$), etc. (Actually, we can deduce the SNF
of $B_n$ directly from that of $C_n$ since for the partition
$(n,n-1,\dots,1)$ we can work over $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)}[x]$ rather than
$\mathbb{Q}[x]$.) We get that the $i$th largest diagonal element of
the SNF is $\prod_u(n+1+c(u))$, where $u$ ranges over all squares of the
$i$th diagonal hook of the partition $(n,n-1,\dots,1)$, and $c(u)$ is the content of the square $u$. This
product is just $(2n-2i+2)!/(2i-1)!$, so over the integers the $i$th
largest diagonal element of the SNF of $B_n$ is the
largest power of 2 dividing $(2n-2i+2)!/(2i-1)!$.

Comment: Very nice, indeed.